# Entity Framework Core + API .NET Core + n to n relationship

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm discovering .NET Core with Entity Framework.

There is my data structure:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Data1> Datas1 { get; set; }
}

public class Data1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public List<Data1_Data2> Datas2 { get; set; }
}

public class Data2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Data1_Data2> Datas1 { get; set; }
}

public class Data1_Data2
{
    public int Data1Id { get; set; }
    public Data1 Data1 { get; set; }
    public int Data2Id { get; set; }
    public Data2 Data2 { get; set; }
}
```

My objective is to retrieve all Data2 objects owned by the User.

In fact, I'm trying to do with EF this request:

```
SELECT d.* FROM User a
INNER JOIN
Data1 b
ON a.Id = b.UserId
INNER JOIN
Data1_Data2 c
ON
c.Data1Id = b.Id
INNER JOIN
Data2 d
ON
d.Id = c.Data2Id
WHERE a.Id = <myId>
```

For now, I'm using EF like this:

```
User dbUser = await _context.Users.Include(u => u.Datas1).ThenInclude(b => b.Datas2).ThenInclude(lb => lb.Data1).FirstAsync(u => u.Id == <myId>);

List<Data2> datas2List = new List<Data2>();

foreach (Data1 b in dbUser.Data1s)
{
    foreach (Data1_Data2 lb in b.Datas2)
    {
        Datas2List.Add(lb.Data2);
    }
}
```

Can I get only a list of Data2 without download all the data? For example, if User is relative to 1M+ Data1 objects, my memory will explode. And I don't want to put User in Data2 for structure purpose. I'm looking for something like this:

```
List<Data2> datas2List = await _context.<myStuff>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly you can put `.SelectMany(u => u.Datas1.Select(x => x.Datas2))` in your lambda expression.

So full command will be, insted to saving data to `User dbUser` now you are expecting `List<Data2> datas2List`:

```csh
List<Data2> datas2List = await _context.Users
                                       .Include(u => u.Datas1)
                                       .ThenInclude(b => b.Datas2)
                                       .ThenInclude(lb => lb.Data1)
                                       .Where(u => u.Id == <myId>)
                                       .SelectMany(u => u.Datas1.Select(x => x.Datas2))
                                       .Tolist();
```

This command will generate in the `SELECT` only to retrive data for `Datas2`.